# 64 bit Compute Parity Returning Strange Answer

Tags: c++, parity

I am trying to find the parity of numbers using a simple loop that checks each set bit and increments a counter.  I seem to have an extra bit though at addresses outside of 32 bits.  For example, when trying to find the parity of 1, which should be odd and have a '1' at index 0, I am getting a '1' at indexes 0 and 32.  Any help would be appreciated.  The code and output are below:

C++ Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>


bool compute_parity(int64_t val){
  int int_size = 64;
  int par_sum = 0;
  printf("indexes where there are '1's:\n");
  for(int i=0; i<int_size;i++){
    if(val & 1<<i){
      printf("%d\n", i);
      par_sum++;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("number of '1's: %d\n", par_sum);
  printf("\n");
  if(par_sum & 1)//if par_sum is odd
    return true;
  return false;
}

int main(){
  //int64_t val = 9223372036854775807;
  int64_t val = 1;
  printf("parity: %s\n", compute_parity(val) ? "odd" : "even");
}
```

Output for compute_parity(1):

```
indexes where there are '1's:
0
32

number of '1's: 2

parity: even
```

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour.  You should use `(uint64_t)1 << i`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Why the cast, why not `1ULL << i`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Because `uint64_t` is guaranteed to be 64-bits.  It's possible that `ULL` is guaranteed to be at least 64-bit too (I don't recall), but IMO it's semantically clearer to use an explicit sized type here.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem.  Could please explain why my code invoked undefined behavior?  Is it because the '1' I was shifting was a 32 bit integer and I was trying to shift it further?

Comment: You can also use one of the less well known parts of `<stdint.h>`, namely the macros for expressing constants of the appropriate type.  In this case, `UINT64_C(1)` matches the type passed into the function.